# Euro format kendo grid column Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a column in kendo which is amount, This column is presented in the dollar format, The corresponding column details are

```
{
  field: 'INVOICE_AMOUNT_ORIGINAL',
  title: $translate.instant('invoiceAmount'),
  format: '{0:n}',
  headerTemplate: '{{ \'invAmount\' | translate }}',
  attributes: {
    style: 'text-align: right;'
  },
  width: 115
},
```

I now want this format to be changed in Euro format, Afte reading from kendo documentary, I tried the format in above code to be this : '{0:c}', but it gives the dollar symbol in front, How can i convert the format to Euro. I do not want any conversion, but just the format from dollar to euro

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define what currency you have like [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-format):

```
---
[format]="{ style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }",
---
```

Another solution might be [this](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/develop/docs/num-formatting/index.md) approach:

```
 ---
 format: '{0:c3}', // converts to euro (according to the site)
 ---
```

Comment: I tried both of the steps, but after trying the first change you said, the whole kendo grid did not showed up. The second approach worked to put the currency symbol ($ and not euro symbol) infront of the grid column but i need to change the format too. One more thing i did applying the culture: 'de-DE', but it does not have any effect.